# Creating file path with config file, string.format() and pathlib Path

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

This seems trivial, but I'm having trouble creating a path using pathlib's Path().

First, I gather user input for the location they want their output directory via a config file.

Then I create an instance variable with the file paths:

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

class MyStuff():
    def __init__(self,
                 output_file):
        self.output_file = output_file

    ## Setup logging ###
    today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    now = time.strftime("%Y%d%m_%H:%M:%S")
    today_file = "{}_ShortStack.log".format(today)
```

And next I'm trying to create the log file with today's date. I've tried the following:

```
log_file = Path("{}{}".format(self.log_path, today_file))

log_file = Path(self.log_path / today_file)

log_file = Path(self.log_path.joinpath(Path(today_file)))
```

If someone enters:

```
output_dir =./
```

on their config file, pathlib keeps putting quotes around it no matter what I try, as shown below:

```
"./"20181221_ShortStack.log
```

I've also tried doing this first, to see if it helped. It did not.

```
self.output_file = Path(output_file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
log_file = Path(self.log_path) / today_file
```

You want the first object to be of type `Path`, rest can be strings as pathlib takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need here is `os.path.join`:

```
log_file = os.path.join(self.log_path, today_file)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do know how to do this using os. I'm trying to figure out how to do it with pathlib specifically. I need the platform agnosticism, and overall, it's easier to accomplish this with pathlib than os.

Comment: `os.path` is platform agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

welp. After much fussing around, this did the trick:

```
log_file = Path(Path(self.log_path) / Path(today_file))
```